# Get a weekly percentile in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need some help with the following, please & thanks in advance.

I have the following code to group by weeks:

```
weekdf = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['type', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-SAT')])['id'].count())
```

It gives me the following df:

```
type        date        id  
expired     2019-11-09  62
            2019-11-16  87
            2019-11-23  26
multi       2019-11-09  10
            2019-11-16  14
            2019-11-23  8
single      2019-11-09  296
            2019-11-16  300
            2019-11-23  230
```

What I would like is to have a df that gives me the weekly percent of the total.

Something like...

percent = per week, count / sum of expired, multi & single id's:

```
type        date        id   percent
expired     2019-11-09  62   16.85%
            2019-11-16  87   21.70%
            2019-11-23  26   9.85%
multi       2019-11-09  10   2.72%
            2019-11-16  14   3.49%
            2019-11-23  8    3.03%
single      2019-11-09  296  80.43%
            2019-11-16  300  74.81%
            2019-11-23  230  87.12%
```

Thanks for the help!

Code to reproduce the dataframe:

```
l = [{'type': 'expired', 'date': '09-11-2019', 'id': 62},
{'type': 'expired', 'date': '16-11-2019', 'id': 87},
 {'type': 'expired', 'date': '23-11-2019', 'id': 26},
 {'type': 'multi', 'date': '09-11-2019', 'id': 10},
 {'type': 'multi', 'date': '16-11-2019', 'id': 14},
 {'type': 'multi', 'date': '23-11-2019', 'id': 8},
 {'type': 'single', 'date': '09-11-2019', 'id': 296},
 {'type': 'single', 'date': '16-11-2019', 'id': 300},
 {'type': 'single', 'date': '23-11-2019', 'id': 230}]

weekdf = pd.DataFrame(l)
weekdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(weekdf['date'])
weekdf = weekdf.set_index(['type','date'])
print(weekdf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`df.index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) to get values of the first level of the multiindex , then get the week and group:

```
weekdf['percent'] = (weekdf['id'].div(weekdf.groupby(weekdf.index.get_level_values(-1).week)
                ['id'].transform('sum')).mul(100).round(2).astype(str).add('%'))
print(weekdf)
```

---

```
                     id percent
type    date                   
expired 2019-09-11   62  16.85%
        2019-11-16   87   21.7%
        2019-11-23   26   9.85%
multi   2019-09-11   10   2.72%
        2019-11-16   14   3.49%
        2019-11-23    8   3.03%
single  2019-09-11  296  80.43%
        2019-11-16  300  74.81%
        2019-11-23  230  87.12%
```

Comment: wow thank you so much! I was struggling with the multiindex, I understand now.